# How do I use this idiom ? " pins and needles " naturally?

Tags: grammar, idioms

I'm just curious. 
how can I use this " pins and needles " idiom  naturally in everyday life ?

like

"Ouooch  I **had** pins and needles right now ! "

or

"Ouooch  I **have** pins and needles right now ! "

or

"Ouooch  I **got** pins and needles right now ! "

which one ?

Comment: Dear Polyglot, this is our second invitation for you to look at other people's edits to your posts and learn from them. The number of invitations left is not unlimited. Thank you.

Comment: http://www.reference.com/example-sentences/pins-and-needles

Comment: The first is wrong, because the tenses don't match.  The second is correct.  The third is rather informal, but not actually wrong.

Comment: In British English, _I've got_ is probably the most common form.

Answer (score 1):

A common expression is "sitting on pins and needles" which means highly agitated while waiting for something to happen.  The expected event can be either good or bad.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pins-and-needles

A secondary use refers to uncomfortable tingling (often in your legs) after a long period of immobility.

Here's a way to use it:
"Flying economy class from London to Hong Kong, I got pins and needles in my legs when I got up.  They got so bad I had to be taken off on a stretcher!"